# Read execution plan in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization, sql-execution-plan

**my question is why there is the full access in the option however I create two index for LIGPOR and DATRAI tables ??**
and if there is any one can help me to clearly read the long execution plan in sql oracle

I have this query :

```
select * 
    FROM DATRAI D,
    LIGPOR L 
    WHERE  D.COMAR= L.COMAR  
    and TO_CHAR(l.daprm,'yyyy') ='2017';
```

and this is the execution plan

```
 SQL_ID  0v5mmx6sg8scu, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select  * FROM LIGPOR L,DATRAI D WHERE  D.COMAR= L.COMAR and 
TO_CHAR(l.daprm,:"SYS_B_0") =:"SYS_B_1"
 
Plan hash value: 3308708566
 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |       |       |     9 (100)|          |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |         |     1 |  2177 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |         |     1 |  2177 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | LIGPOR  |     1 |  2138 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | DATRAI1 |     1 |       |     0   (0)|          |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DATRAI  |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01
```

the tables creations

```
CREATE TABLE "user"."LIGPOR" 
       (
        "COINT" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "COMAR" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
            "DAPRM" DATE
             ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
      PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
     NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)

CREATE TABLE "user"."DATRAI" 
   (    "COMAR" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DATRA" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
 ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
```

the indexes creation

```
CREATE INDEX "user"."LIGPOR5" ON "user"."LIGPOR" ("COMAR") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "user"."DATRAI1" ON "user"."DATRAI" ("COMAR") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 NOLOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "UBIX_TABLES" ;
```

*thix :)*

Comment: On a sidenote: You are using an ancient join syntax. It has been made redundant in standard SQL in 1992. It took Oracle nine years to implement the new explicit joins, but this was more than twenty years ago. Don't use those error-prone comma-separated joins. Use explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.).

Comment: Please add the `Predicate Information` from the execution plan - this is the **crutial** information to interpret the lines 3 and 4 (marked with an asterix). How large is your table `LIGPOR`? If it contains **one row** as the plan suggest you *either* should not fear the *full scan* **or** you should verify your *object statistics*.

Comment: You don't need to share the PCTFREE, PCTUSED, INITRANS, MAXTRANS etc settings, as they are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The SQL you're using is very simple and the plan is very simple also. What the DB is doing is starting with one table, here it chose LIGPO, reading the data using a full scan, as there are no predicates that allows it to use the index. Then, for each row, it uses the index on the second table to see if there are any matching rows (as the second table has an index on the COMAR column). If it finds one it uses the rowid given by the index to read the remaining data from the table. Depeding on the size of your table it may choose to do it the other way around, i.e. start with DATRAI using a full scan, the use the index to check for the matching rows in LIGPO.

What the optimizer does depends on the statistics on the objects, and with a query like yours, it may well choose to do a hash join with a full scan of both tables.

Last remark: do NOT write predicates like `TO_CHAR(l.daprm,'yyyy') ='2017'`, because even if you had an index on DAPRM, the database would not use it. Better do something like `ldaprm >= date '2017-01-01' and ldaprm < date '2018-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1):

First you must realize that the general rule **Index quick - Full table scan slow** has few exceptions.

The most obvious are

- the table is *small* it consist only of few blocks (a simgle *mutiblock read* is better that repeated jumping between the index and the table)
- you want to access a *large part* of the table data (again you *die* in switching between the index and the table)

I guess *the first point* is your case.

Let's try to simulate it. Basically you have a *parent* `DATRAI`-  *child* `LIGPOR` tables, connected by the `PK/FK` column `COMAR`.

**Sample Data**

```
create table DATRAI as
select  rownum  COMAR,
date'2017-01-01' + rownum DATRA
from dual connect by level <= 2;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "DATRAI1" ON  "DATRAI" ("COMAR"); 

create table LIGPOR as
select rownum COINT,
mod(rownum,1000)+1 COMAR,
date'2017-01-01' + rownum DAPRM
from dual connect by level <= 20;

CREATE INDEX "LIGPOR5" ON  "LIGPOR" ("COMAR");
```

*Note* that I'm on 18g, where the *object statistics* are [online gathered](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/optimizer-statistics-concepts.html#GUID-E920301F-FFC4-4AB7-8DEB-11BA56088E0B) in create table and index, in former versions you'd need add a call of `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats`

**OLTP Example**

Let's start with the typical example (you probably have in mind) - you constraint  the parent with the *primary key* (`COMAR = 10`) and access all coresponding child rows with the *foreign key*.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'EXPL_1' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT * 
FROM DATRAI D 
JOIN LIGPOR L ON D.COMAR= L.COMAR 
WHERE  
D.COMAR = 10 AND
TO_CHAR(l.daprm,'yyyy') ='2017';

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'EXPL_1','ALL'));

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |         |     1 |    28 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                        |         |     1 |    28 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | DATRAI  |     1 |    12 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | DATRAI1 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| LIGPOR  |     1 |    16 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | LIGPOR5 |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("D"."COMAR"=10)
   4 - filter(TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("L"."DAPRM"),'yyyy')='2017')
   5 - access("L"."COMAR"=10)
```

Short note **how to read the execution plan**

You start with the row with the first row with highest intend, i.e. the row with `Id = 3`.

The `Id` is marked with an asterix, so you check the `Predicate Information` for the *access / filter* condition - here `access("D"."COMAR"=10)`

Ths means you use the *index* (index name is in the column `Name`) to select as Oracle informs you in the colum `Rows` *one* row.

Next (`Id = 2`) you take the `rowid` from the index to access the table

Next (`Id = 1`) you are in `NESTED LOOPS`, i.e. for each row you perform the line with `Id 5 and 4`, i.e. again *index acccess* with `access("L"."COMAR"=10)` followed with the *rowid table access*.

Note the `BATCHED` is an optimization in recent version - that I can't much comment.

*So I guess - this is the execution plan you will enjoy*.

**Other Example**

Let go back to your example, which is basically the same query - only *without the PK predicate*.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'EXPL_2' into   plan_table  FOR
SELECT * 
FROM DATRAI D 
JOIN LIGPOR L ON D.COMAR= L.COMAR 
WHERE  
TO_CHAR(l.daprm,'yyyy') ='2017';  

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'EXPL_2','ALL'));


----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |     1 |    25 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |         |     1 |    25 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |         |     1 |    25 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL         | LIGPOR  |     1 |    14 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | DATRAI1 |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| DATRAI  |     1 |    11 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - filter(TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("L"."DAPRM"),'yyyy')='2017')
   4 - access("D"."COMAR"="L"."COMAR")
```

Again the starting line is `Id = 3`, but here Oracle choose to start with the *child* table `LIGPOR`. Why? There is at least a *filter* predicate for `Id = 3` which makes it cheaper for Oracle *Cost Based Optimizer*.

The *alternative* would be a full scan of the table `DATRAI` where you have no *filter* at all.

*Note the critical difference between an **access** predicate - active index selection - and a **filter** predicate - you must process all rows and some of them discard.

The rest is basically the same *nested loops* as before, only technically performed *twice* first index access than the table access.

To not make the answer extreme long, I make the **Summary**

- Do not fear `table access full` prematurely
- Don't use `select *` if you can limit the result column - this could enable Oracle a better optimization